# Form that appears only upon first sigIn

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using React and AWS Amplify library to sign up and perform Auth for a Project of mine. Now I want to create a form that appears only once(for the user to add extra data to the database e.g adress) and it should appear when a user registers and signsin for the first time and after that never again. I have been unable to figure out how to go about doing this especially setting the conditionthat it only appears upon first signin. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Add the form the inputs you need for the *register/signup* page? I can only make aassumptions as your question is too broad this way. Please share your code to make people understand what exactly goes on. Oh, welcome btw.

Comment: well the form looks like this                                                                                                 '<form>
  <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="street" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>'                                                                        and i want it to appear once after the first signin. Hope you can understand now.Thanks!

Comment: I know I can add it to the register page but I was checking if they were other ways. For example like when one creates a google account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a couple of paths.

I assume that the information that you want the user to store will be either a user attribute in your Cognito user pool or in a separate database. I'll assume that you'll be using UserAttributes for the answer.

Show only once (I assume you mean on login, and the user can access this some other way):

1. When the user is presented with the form for the first time, update their profile with an attribute called seenForm (or whatever).
2. Check if the user has that attribute when they log in

   ```
   showForm = async() => {
     await Auth.updateUserAttributes({ // this sets the seenform attribute in the user's profile to make sure that they are not shown it again
       seenForm: true
     })
     ...
   }
   checkUserAttributes = async () => {
     await Auth.userAttributes()
     .then(async (userAttributes) => {
       // check to see if the attribute field exists
       !userAttributes['seenForm'] ? this.showForm() : null
     }
   }

   async componentDidMount() {
     checkUserAttributes()
   }
   ```

If the attribute exists, skip showing the form. Otherwise, set the attribute and show the form.

It works better this way than using local storage in case the user logs in with a different device.